# The run speed doesn't change in my unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a starter and I am trying to make a simple unity top-down game in 2d, so i made a player controller script and tried to make my character walk, run, and crawl. But while executing it I can't make my character run speed change while everything else works.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer rend;
    public float movementSpeed = 3.0f;
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2();
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    [SerializeField] float normalSpeed, runSpeed, crouchSpeed;

    Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateState();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveCharacter();
    }

    private void MoveCharacter()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (movement.x > 0)
        {
            rend.flipX = true;
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0)
        {
            rend.flipX = false;
        }
        
        rigidbody2D.velocity  = movement * movementSpeed;
    }

    private void UpdateState()
    {
        //걷기
        if (Mathf.Approximately(movement.x, 0) && Mathf.Approximately(movement.y, 0))
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMove", false);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMove", true);
        }


        //달리기
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
            movementSpeed = runSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isRun", true);
        }
        else{
            movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isRun", false);
        }


        //웅크리기
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            movementSpeed = crouchSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouch", true);
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouch", false);
        }


        //대기상태 x방향 설정
        if (movement.x > 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 1);
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 0);
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", -1);
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 0);
        }


        //대기상태 y방향 설정
        if (movement.y > 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", 1);
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 0);
        }
        else if (movement.y < 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("verIdle", -1);
            animator.SetFloat("horIdle", 0);
        }

        animator.SetFloat("horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("vertical", movement.y);
    }

    
}
```

This is the code I wrote for the Player's momvement and I can't find any problems here.

Comment: are you sure that you set a greater run speed in the inspector?

Comment: Yea, the normalSpeed is 3.0f, crowlSpeed is 2.0f, runSpeed is in 5.0f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `if` `else` statements that check for the user input, into this:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    movementSpeed = runSpeed;
    animator.SetBool("isRun", true);
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
{
    movementSpeed = crouchSpeed;
    animator.SetBool("isCrouch", true);
}
else
{
    movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
    animator.SetBool("isRun", false);

    movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
    animator.SetBool("isCrouch", false);
}
```

You are using two `if-else` statements to check for the user input. For every `if`, there is an `else`, hence it's ambiguous which `else` has to be executed when there is no user input.

Comment: Oh I see. So the runSpeed was not changing because another else was executing?

Comment: hi @Jagari, that's true

Comment: @GeekyQuentin unfortunately, with this setup there are cases where if you hold both keys down, then release one, you haven't set the corresponding `SetBool` to false. This leaves the possibility of BOTH "isRun" and "isCrouch" active at the same time. It may not be an issue in the animator, as only one branch would likely be taken, but we don't know how the animator is defined.

Comment: You might still want to handle the two `SetBool` calls individually. Only the `movementSpeed` should be handled  via `if - else if - else` ... and you also need to set it only once btw ;)

Comment: I think i got it. It works fine after editing a little bit. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Jagari, if you found a solution that works, please consider posting it as an answer so that it can be helpful for the people that might have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to keep my `if` statements as simple as possible. That way, there's less likelihood of introducing a logic error.

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 3.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float normalSpeed, runSpeed, crouchSpeed;

    private Vector2 movement;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

    Animator animator;

    void Start ( )
    {
        movement = Vector2.zero;
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ( );
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ( );
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ( );
    }

    private void FixedUpdate ( )
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = movement * movementSpeed;
    }

    private void Update ( )
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw ( "Horizontal" );
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw ( "Vertical" );

        if ( movement.x > 0 )
            rend.flipX = true;
        else if ( movement.x < 0 )
            rend.flipX = false;

        //걷기
        animator.SetBool ( "isMove", movement != Vector2.zero );
        movementSpeed = normalSpeed;

        // We can check the key codes in one place, outside of any conditional code.
        // Note that both isRun and isCrouch at the same time might be a valid condition?
        var isCrouch = Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.LeftControl );
        var isRun = Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.LeftShift );
        // If run requires crouch to be false, then the following line checks for that:
        // var isRun = !isCrouch && Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.LeftShift );
        

        //달리기
        animator.SetBool ( "isRun", isRun );
        if ( isRun ) movementSpeed = runSpeed;

        //웅크리기
        // Crouch is checked after Run. This makes crouch speed override run speed if both keys are pressed.
        animator.SetBool ( "isCrouch", isCrouch );
        if ( isCrouch ) movementSpeed = crouchSpeed;

        // Here we assume that idle will be zero when there is no 'movement'
        Vector2 idle = Vector2.zero;

        // If there is movement then we update the idle value.
        //대기상태 x방향 설정
        if ( movement.x > 0 )
            idle.x = 1;
        else if ( movement.x < 0 )
            idle.x = -1;

        //대기상태 y방향 설정
        if ( movement.y > 0 )
            idle.y = 1;
        else if ( movement.y < 0 )
            idle.y = -1;

        animator.SetFloat ( "verIdle", idle.x );
        animator.SetFloat ( "horIdle", idle.y );

        animator.SetFloat ( "horizontal", movement.x );
        animator.SetFloat ( "vertical", movement.y );
    }
}
```

Comment: To even reduce a bit more clutter you could use [`idle.x = Math.Sign(movement.x);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math.sign) (not to confuse with Unity's [`Mathf.Sign`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html) which for some reason returns `1` for input of `0` ^^)

Comment: @OP you might also want to additionally clamp the input so that diagonal movement isn't faster than single axis: [`idle = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(idle, 1f);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html) and accordingly also `movement = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(movement, 1f);`

Comment: Oh i was having issues with diagonal speed. This gave an answer to me. Thanks!